# Compression tools that recurse into directories

Tags: recursion, compression

For future reference, I want to compile a list of compression tools that are able to recurse into directories.

For example, `gzip -r <directory>` recurses into directories, and compresses every file it finds. On the other hand, `zip -r foo.zip foo` does not do what I mean - it recurses into the `foo` directory, and appends all zipped files to a single archive, `foo.zip`.

**These tools don't have a built-in method for recursing into directories:**

bzip2

lzma

lrzip

xz

zip

**These tools can recurse into directories**

gzip (`grzip -r`)

lrzip (version 0.630)

Are there any tools I missed?

Comment: The page https://www.mattmahoney.net/dc/text.html lists and compares a lot of text compression tools. It is only run on a single file but might be a good starting point if you want to look for more tools. Whether binary files or recursion are supported is not listed and needs to be checked on your own. -- I would also think you can combine a lot of single file compressors with `tar` to add multi-file support. For e.g. `gzip` in `*.tar.gz` etc there is automatic support but for others piping or scripting might be required.

Answer (score 1):

The latest version of lrzip (0.630) does do recursion.

Comment: Thank you, Con! lrzip seems to be the turbo-charged diesel chainsaw of file compression, and I'm amazed that such a thing exists.

Answer (score 0):

Anything can be made to do that quite easily:

```
find directory_to_compress -type f -exec compressor -o {}.compressed {} \;
```

Comment: Of course I could do this, or I could hack something in R quite easily. But I'm rather interested in compression tools do have that recursion already built in.

Comment: Why?  If you're just curious, that's fine (frankly, the world could use more of that :)), I'm just wondering if you think integrating the feature into the tool itself is useful for some reason…